# Webmin Monitoring - Sendmail and postfix

Tags: centos, email, postfix, sendmail

I have Webmin currently installed to help manage my CentOS server and I have configued it to send email alerts for different things, backups, service failures etc.
However not one email is arriving in the mailbox.

I have done a quick test by using sendmail at the command line to send an email and it worked, no log files anywhere seem to show any errors - there are just no emails arriving.

Does anyone know of anywhere else I could look to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check the config files for webmin to make sure it has the right path to the mail program to execute.

Secondly make sure that you have configured whatever cron job or system is responsible for periodically running these checks and sending notifications.